# Make a proper login form in Delphi 10.3 using SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firemonkey

edit: How to retrieve and store user credenials from SQLServer database using adoquery in order to compare them with what the user entered

Comment: Do you already know something about using a SQLServer database with Delphi? If not, first read the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Developing_Database_Applications_Index and then write your first simple program to access your DB, then ask more specific questions when you are blocked.

Comment: Also before coming back here, look at this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTgLg97XScw

Comment: I know how to access and display data using the diiferrent tools, however, you don't have to display it a login form.

Comment: thank you for the link, I've already seen this video, and I have no problem whatsoever with displaying the database in delphi

Comment: A login form is nothing special! Edit your question and be much more specific about what you don't know or don't understand. Only a simple thing, a simple and unique question. Show the code you have managed to write and ask a question about what doesn't work with your code. This is how StackOverflow works. If you don't follow the rules, your question will be closed (You already got one vote for close. The third will effectively close your question). That's not what you want.

Comment: If you don't know how to execute an SQL query, you should start with that.

Comment: And, before that of course, you must learn the basics of the SQL language (if not already done).

Comment: sorry for not being accurate enough, what I want to know is the method or the process to follow to make a proper login, I don"t really have poblems with my code. so I guess this question will be closed, it's okay!

Comment: If you open the SqlServer table using, say, a TFDQuery, you could use its .Locate() function to see it it can find the user's credentials.

Comment: The "process" is to query the user table to retrieve the row corresponding to the user. It's just basic SQL manipulation. Nothing specific to login.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: prooer = done the good way(secure and reliable)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (Out of my memory, not tested):

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT UserCode FROM Credentials ' +
                      'WHERE (UserCode = :UserCode) ' +
                        'AND (Password = :Password)';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('UserCode').Value := FUserCode;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Password').Value := FPassword;
ADOQuery1.Open;
if ADOQuery1.Eof then
    ShowMessage('Invalid credentials')
else
    ShowMessage('OK')
```

BTW: Not a good idea to store the password in the database. Use a hash code instead.

BTW2: I returned UserCode, but probably you would return some more useful information like permission, last login or other. I don't know what you have at hand.

Comment: how do I do that? and does that make the code you just showed me invalid?

Comment: @Ash: If your application is for your family photo albums on your home LAN or a toy or learning project, this is good enough. If you are writing enterprise applications professionally, you need to learn all the basics the proper way: spending a few months reading books, playing around, etc. You can't use SO as a replacement.

Comment: it's not for a professional project, I'm just "learning"

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I agree.  There seems to be an unfortunate trend on SO lately of users trying to use it to incrementally code some topic like this and an equally unfortunately trend of answers pandering to them.

Comment: @fpiette With `count(*)`, you always get 1 record.

Comment: @olivier You are right, edited my answer.

Comment: @ash How you do hash? First do some search by yourself (Google is your friend). Then try to write some code, then if you are stuck ask ANOTHER question. StackOverflow is not a service to write code for you. It is to help you correcting your bugs or moving you to the right track.

Comment: Better to use `if not AdoQuery1.IsEmpty` instead of `if AdoQuery1.Eof`.